# $\theta \ni \mathbf{f}(x)=\cos ^{2} x+\cos ^{2}(x+\theta)-\cos x \cos (x+\theta)$ Is a constant function of $\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Determine a value of the parameter $\theta \ni \mathbf{f}(x)=\cos ^{2} x+\cos ^{2}(x+\theta)-\cos x \cos (x+\theta)$
Is a constant function of $\mathbf{x}$ ?

I am trying to solve the problem expanding the cosine term but proved fruitless!
Any hint or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you experimented with values of $x$?

Comment: No! I have not tried hit and trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=0$, we have $f(0)=1+\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta$. For $x=\pi/2$ we have $f(\pi/2)=0+\sin^2\theta$, so we need
$$
1+\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta=\sin^2\theta
$$
that means $2\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta=0$. Thus either $\cos\theta=0$ or $\cos\theta=1/2$.

Can you finish?

Comment: That doesn’t prove $f(x)=f(0)$ for all values of $x$.

Comment: @Tavish Certainly not! But it gives you just four possible values of $\theta$ (in the interval $[0,2\pi]$) to check.

Comment: @ egreg  yeah! thanks

Comment: @AmartyaRoy I preferred just to give a hint to get you started, rather than the full solution: one learns better this way.

Comment: i agree. thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

In order that $f(x)$ to be a constant function of $x$, we simply let its derivative to be zero, i.e.,
\begin{align}
0 &= f'(x) \\
  &= -2 \cos(x) \sin(x) - 2 \cos(x + \theta) \sin(x + \theta)
  + \sin(x) \cos(x + \theta) + \cos(x) \sin(x + \theta) \\
  & = -\sin(2 x) - \sin(2 x + 2 \theta) + \sin(2 x + \theta).
\end{align}
This has to be true for any $x$, therefore, we let $x = 0$,
then $0 = -\sin(2 \theta)+\sin(\theta)$, namely, $\sin(\theta)=0$
or $\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}$.

If $\sin(\theta)=0$, then $\cos(\theta)=\pm 1$,
$f(x) = \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x+\theta) - \cos(x)\cos(x+\theta)
= \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x)  \mp \cos^2(x) $ is not a constant function
of $x$;

If $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\sin(\theta)=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$,
it can be easily verified
$f(x) = \cos^2(x) + \cos^2(x+\theta) - \cos(x)\cos(x+\theta) = \frac{3}{4}$,
so this is our solution.

Comment: Formatting tip.  Your posts will look better and be easier to read if you write \sin and \cos and similarly for other common functions.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way that I thought I’d share:

Note$$f(x)=\frac{2\cos^2x+2\cos^2(x+\theta) -2\cos x\cos(x+\theta)}{2}\\=\frac{2+\cos 2x+\cos(2x+2\theta)-\cos(2x+\theta)-\cos\theta}{2}\\=\frac{2+2\cos(2x+\theta)\cos\theta -\cos(2x+\theta)-\cos\theta}{2}\\=1+\cos(2x+\theta)\cos\theta-\frac 12\cos(2x+\theta)-\frac 12\cos\theta\\=1-\frac12\cos\theta+\cos(2x+\theta) \left[\cos\theta-\frac 12\right]$$ We need this to be a constant for all $x$. Observe the only term containing $x$, the rightmost term. If we can somehow make that equal to $0$ for all $x$, we would be done. This would require $$\cos\theta-\frac 12=0 \implies \theta=2n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$$
and $$f(x)=1-\frac12\cdot\frac 12 =\frac 34$$